# Not getting correct return value from geocoder?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I've an array of locations and, using geocoder, I was able to get the latitude & longitude. However, I want to pass the location value each time out of the geocoder function.

```
var locations=new Array("Delhi","Jaipur")
for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
var tempLoc=locations[i];        
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': tempLoc},function(results, status)
{
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

              latitude[i] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              longitude[i] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();          
     latLonArray[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]); 
     latlngbounds.extend( latLonArray[ i ] );
     map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
              map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);                     
              createMarker(latLonArray[i],tempLoc);
        }             
});

}

function createMarker(pos,t){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
    position: pos, 
    map: map, 
    title: t      
}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
infowindow.open(map, marker);

}); 
return marker;  
}
```

The locations are  marking perfectly, but when a click event is called the info window is not showing according to the location (for every marker the info window shows the title as last location["jaipur"]).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the response from geocoder is asynchronous. The `for` loop goes through each element, and since 'Jaipur' is the last value, that is the value still stored in tempLoc when the response from geocoder finally comes in and calls createMarker:

```
createMarker(latLonArray[i],tempLoc);   
// by this time tempLoc always equals tempLoc=locations[locations.length-1];
```

What you actually want to do is get the name back that geocoder returned

```
results[0].address_components[0].long_name
```

So your call to createMarker will look like:

```
createMarker(latLonArray[i], results[0].address_components[0].long_name );
```